# MISSING UPDATES FOR: MEDIA Drupal 9

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have started facing an issue with locally hosted Drupal 9 (Xampp, Windows 10). The issue started when I was trying to create events in drupal 9 and I was redirected to Install.PHP page. However, upon checking I was redirected to Update.php and the error seems to be as mentioned below.

**Install.PHP page message:**

> Drupal 9.2.2 Drupal already installed To start over, you must empty
> your existing database and copy default.settings.php over
> settings.php. To upgrade an existing installation, proceed to the
> update script. View your existing site.

**Update.php Page Message:**

> MISSING UPDATES FOR: MEDIA The installed version of the Media module
> is too old to update. Update to a version prior to 9.0.0 first
> (missing updates: media_post_update_collection_route,
> media_post_update_storage_handler,
> media_post_update_enable_standalone_url,
> media_post_update_add_status_extra_filter).

I'm well aware of the fact that Media is a core module and I havent tried upgrading it or my site. My site has always been a D9 installation and there were no migrations etc. I would really appreciate expert help on this issue.

Comment: Hi Syed,
check if you have all dependencies installed via Composer. After that try to update database using drush updatedb command and then clear cache with drush cr.

Answer (score 1):

Running this in a function in my .theme file did the trick for me:

```
\Drupal::service('update.post_update_registry')
->registerInvokedUpdates(['media_post_update_collection_route', 'media_post_update_storage_handler', 'media_post_update_enable_standalone_url', 'media_post_update_add_status_extra_filter', 'setting functions as applied according_to_the_error_message']);
```

I personally used hook_theme() (Make sure to clear your cache for it to run and also remove this code once the issue is fixed.)

Comment: I don't know the syntax for hook_theme() - can you please write what I need in my mytheme.theme file?